# How can we use instance variables in RestEasy?

Tags: java, resteasy, instance-variables

I am trying to learn Restful Web Service with RestEasy. I created a Java class and tried to use a instance variable but default scope is Request Scope and after an event, the value of variable is cleaned. How can we use a instance variable in different methods in RestEasy class.
My code is below:

```
        /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package restService;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

    /**
     *
     * @author ilkaygunel
     */
    @Path("/service")
    public class Service {
        Map<Integer, String> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();



    @GET
    @Path("/show")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Map show()
    {
        return employeeMap;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/addRecord")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Map addRecord(Employee employee) {
        employeeMap.put(employee.getEmployeeId(), employee.getEmployeeName()+" "+employee.getEmployeeSurname());
        System.out.println("@POST ile işaretlenmiş metoda gelen veri:");
        System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeId());
        System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeName());
        System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeSurname());

        System.out.println("---HashMap İçindeki Veri (POST Metodundan)---");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : employeeMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() +" " +entry.getValue());
        }
        return employeeMap;
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("/updateRecord")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void updateRecord(Employee employee) {
        System.out.println("@PUT ile işaretlenmiş metoda gelen veri:");
        System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeId());
        System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeName());
        System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeSurname());

        System.out.println("HashMap'in Boyutu:"+employeeMap.size());

        for(Integer key : employeeMap.keySet()) {
            if(key ==employee.getEmployeeId())
            {
                System.out.println("Buraya Bak:"+employeeMap.get(key));
                employeeMap.put(key, employee.getEmployeeName()+" "+employee.getEmployeeSurname());
            }
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("---HashMap İçindeki Veri (PUT Metodundan)---");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : employeeMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() +" " +entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    @DELETE
    public void deleteRecord() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to inject some singleton service class e.g. `EmploeeManager` which contains map of employees. (I don't know what technology are you using spring/cdi)

On the other hand you can use

```
private static Map<Integer, String> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and think also about synchronization since it can be accessed by multiple thread at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what the [JAX-RS 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) defines regarding the lifecycle of the resource classes:

> **3.1.1 Lifecycle and Environment**
>
> By default a new resource class instance is created for each request
>   to that resource. First the constructor is called, then any requested
>   dependencies are injected, then the appropriate method is invoked and
>   finally the object is made available for garbage collection. [...]

The behavior you described in the question is expected: a new instance of the resource class is getting created for each request.

To store data, you can use the following approaches:

- Use a `static` field, that is, a field that is shared by all instances of a class;
- Use dependency injection frameworks such as CDI or Spring and store your data into application scoped bean or singleton. This bean can be injected into your resource class.
- Use a database.